# NetCore project does not publish, keeps giving error of versioning mismatch

Tags: visual-studio-2017, publish

I have a asp.net core project and it's supporting libraries all in .net core version 2.2. They run, I can debug, they also work in release mode. However when I try to publish them, I get a list of errors. The main cause is shown as the web project:

> Error NU1202: Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 supports: netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2)

after which this error keeps repeating for every project that the web project references/uses in the solution.

I have verified the dependencies and here's what I see in the web project:

[image: AspCoreApp]

and this:

[image: NEtCoreApp]

as you can see the project references the latest version 2.2.0. So I have no idea where is it picking this netcoreapp2.1?

if that is the problem with configuration, why this error does not show up during debug and release build or even debugging. Just to note my publish is based on Release build and it uses netcore 2.2 as framework dependent.

This is what I get if I run dotnet --list-runtimes

> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0-preview-18579-0056 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> - Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> - Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> - Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> - Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> - Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> - Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> - Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0-preview-27122-01 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> - Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0-alpha-27128-4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: Can you add details about your publish? `RuntimeIdentifier` and more details from the `.csproj`? It may seem obvious to you, but we need to know the overall picture you see.

Comment: <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is likely to do with your publish settings in Visual Studio. You have two ways of fixing the issue.

Option A. Edit the file FolderProfile.pubxml under the folder \Properties\PublishProfiles directly and change the target framework from 2.1 to 2.2 under:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

or

Option B. Go to publish menu and click Configure... It appears that just going to menu and clicking save will fix the issue since the menu defaults to the the project default 2.2.

Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: your explanation makes sense. that's what I did to fix the issue. forcefully saving it.

Comment: I really can't believe this worked. It was already set correctly but re-opening the configure publish settings window and clicking save did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your installed **runtime** is `.net core hosting 2.1`.

You should download the [dotnet runtime 2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) or higher version.

Comment: it is installed, as well as I installed 3.0 preview also but still same problem occurs.

Comment: What the output of `dotnet --list-runtimes`?

Comment: Can't paste it in comments... too long

Comment: You should add to the answer, and you don't have to paste all, just paste the relevant runtimes (2.1 and higher).

Comment: Ok I added it to the question. By the way I was able to solve the issue by making some changes in the publishing file and saving it. then reverting it back and saving it again. so technically no changes at all, yet project publishes successfully. that applies to all publishing profile. I'm now more confused about it

Comment: If your project is in source control, you can check if there are any changes in another file.

Comment: none and that's whats puzzling me. Why the error in first place and why saving it forcefully fixes the issue without having any changes? I want to know because if it persisted for days and i would know what to do if that happens again